# Can't import .eps vector graphic in Mathematica 8

Tags: pdf, vector, import, wolfram-mathematica, eps

I'm on Mathematica 8.0.4.0 for Students and despite the fact that `$ImportFormats` returns both eps and pdf, whenever I try to import either of them I just get `$Failed`. 
I've tried *Insert > Picture > From File...*, Drag and Drop and `Import["filepath"]` but no luck.
All I'm trying to do is to insert a vector graphic from Illustrator without having to rastarize it (.png works just fine with all described methods).
Any ideas what I could be doing wrong or how I could import vector graphics?

Comment: export png from illustrator.  mma eps import is extremely limited, as you see.

Comment: Please post problematic .eps file. As to exchanging vector graphics between Illustrator and *Mathematica* it is much better to export as PDF from Illustrator and then `Import` the PDF file in *Mathematica*.